# Progress Indicator in view based table view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsprogressindicator

I am trying to show a custom view containing one `NSProgressIndicator`.

I am changing its doubleValue on each timer event but it doesn't get reflected in `NSProgressIndicator`. It is always in `0` value.

The code I used is as:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    self.progressViewTextField.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row: %ld", row];

    [self.progressViewBar setDoubleValue: [self.progressViewBar doubleValue]+5];

    NSData * archivedView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.progressView];
    NSView * myViewCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedView];

    NSLog(@"progress: %lf", self.progressViewBar.doubleValue);

    return myViewCopy;
}
```

Any help to achieve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to archive then unarchive the view? Try comment out those 3 lines and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer: I did it this way because I need many copies of `self.progressView`. If I omit those 3 lines, only one view in the last row will come. However in this case progressIndicator *indicates*.

Comment: That seems like a weird way to create copies. I'm assuming you're creating a view-based table view? If so try use the method `makeViewWithIdentifier:`, or try switch the order by making a copy via archiving and then changing the progress view's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
@implementation TVAppDelegate{
    NSInteger barValue;
}


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _progressList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];
        
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(timerMethod)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) timerMethod{
    barValue+=2;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView;{
    return self.progressList.count;
    
}


- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    
    NSData * archivedView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.progressView];
    NSView * myViewCopy =[ NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedView];
    
    [[[myViewCopy subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setDoubleValue: [self.progressViewBar doubleValue]+5];
    
    
    [[[myViewCopy subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setDoubleValue: barValue];
    [[[myViewCopy subviews] objectAtIndex:1] startAnimation:self];
    
    return myViewCopy;
}
```